# Winforms Itext Ghost Script Rectangular coordinates selection

Tags: pdf, itext, ghostscript, rectangles

Using C# and Winforms, I want to display a PDF, select a rectangular region, and then extract that area of text from a number of PDFs.  For displaying the PDF, I have a number of options...

1. Use an "Adobe PDF Reader" control to display the PDF - However, I cant use mouseover events and according to https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1640606 its just not possible to select a region.
2. Use a "WebBrowser" control to display the PDF, but it appears I have the same issue with mouseover events and cannot select a region.
3. Convert the PDF to an image (using ghostscript in my case) and displaying it in a picturebox.  I'm finding the most success here, as I can now generate and record the coordinates of a rectangular region.  When I take these coordinates and apply them to the PDF using Itext, I don't think my rectangular region translates correctly.

My question is, How do I render the GhostScripted image in a picture box maintaining the same ratios so that my coordinates will line up with the PDF?

Thank you in advance for the down votes!!

Here is the current state of my code...  Everything works with the exception that my units are off in space somewhere.  The action DOES return text, but it's never the text I selected. Im sure its a combination of the coordinate system / units and I will continue to try to understand this.

---- update

With a PDF at 0 deg rotation (portrait), I think the following holds true, or is at least working for me right now...  User Units having not been changed, the coordinates taken from selecting in the picturebox need adjusting.  The Y coordinates need to be subtracted from the overall height while the X coordinate remains the same.

```
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(first.X, 3024-first.Y, last.X, 3024-last.Y);
```

This is picking text up exactly as expected on 0 deg rotated PDFs.  On 90 deg rotated PDFs, the X and Y coordinates just need to be swapped.I am updating the code snippet below to show my working example.

[image]

```
    using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace formPdf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string fileName;        // The filename of the pdf 
        float width;            // The width of the PDF in pixels
        float hight;            // the Height of the PDF in pixels
        float rotation;         // the Rotation of the PDF 0 or 90
        float llx = 0;          // The Lower Left X value for applying to the PDF
        float lly = 0;          // the Lower Left Y value for applying to the PDF
        float urx = 0;          // the Upper Right X value for applying to the PDF
        float ury = 0;          // the Upper Right Y value for applying to the PDF

        // OnCLick event to open the file browser and select a file...  The Width, Height and rotation values are set and the program
        // is directed to render the First page of the pdf by calling the setPicture function 
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle dim = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);

                    width = dim.Width;
                    hight = dim.Height;
                    rotation = dim.Rotation;

                    setPicture(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                } catch
                {
                    // do nothing for now
                }
            }
        }

        // Using Ghostscript, the image is rendered to a picturebox.  DPIs are set assuming the PDF default value is used
        private void setPicture(string fileName)
        {
            GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();
            rasterizer.Open(fileName);
            Image img = rasterizer.GetPage(72, 72, 1);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
        }

        // Declare point variables for the user defined rectangle indicating the locatoin of the PDF to be searched...
        Point first = new Point();
        Point last = new Point();

        // The first point is collected on the MouseDown event
        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            first = e.Location;
        }

        // The second point is collected on the mouse down event. Points to be applied to the PDF are adjusted based on the rotation of the PDF.
        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            last = e.Location;
            if (rotation == 0)
            {
                llx = first.X;
                lly = hight - first.Y;
                urx = last.X;
                ury = hight - last.Y;
            } else if(rotation == 90) {
                llx = first.Y;
                lly = first.X;
                urx = last.Y;
                ury = last.X;
            }
            gettext();
        }

        // the original PDF is opened with Itext and the text is extracted from t he defined location...
        private void gettext()
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
            RenderFilter[] renderfilter = new RenderFilter[1];
            renderfilter[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
            ITextExtractionStrategy textExtractionStrategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), renderfilter);
            string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, textExtractionStrategy);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
            MessageBox.Show("", text+"  "+mediabox+"  "+first+"  "+last);
        }

        // Image Controls....

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the coordinate system in PDF? Some people say it's upside-down, but that's because they don't know PDF. Do you know the measurement unit in PDF? It's *user units*, and by default they correspond with *points*. When you render the PDF to an image, which resolution are you using? How does the size in pixels of the image of a page relate to the size in user units of the corresponding page in the PDF? Because pixels aren't user units. Answer those questions and you'll know why your rectangular region doesn't translate correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I'm aware that PDF has a coordinate system - but that's about it.  I'm also aware of the user units and they are often valued as null unless this is overwritten.  I'm sure I can get these values from itext and make the appropriate adjustments in ghostscript, I'm just not clear yet how this translation all comes together...  This may be what im loking for http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/inspect-pdf/itext7-how-get-userunit-pdf-file

Comment: You say about user units: *they are often valued as null unless this is overwritten.* That's not true. User units are user units. What you probably mean is that in most cases the default "1 user unit = 1 point" is used, because the value that changes the default is not present (in which case you get a `null` value when you ask for it). As for the broader question, well, it's just too broad. Show us your code, show what you've done, and why you think the pixel coordinates can't be converted to user unit coordinates.